# French municipal elections: How are the seats divided based on the vote?

Tags: election, france

For example, in St-Front-de-Pradoux in 2014, these were the second round results ([source](http://www.annuaire-mairie.fr/elections-municipales-saint-front-de-pradoux.html)):

[image]

This was an unusual election in that Crouzille and Olivier each got 277 votes. French law requires that ties be broken by age. Crouzille's team had a higher average age and so won the tie-breaker.

Reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipal_elections_in_France), I understand for towns with <1,500 pop. (such as this town), there are 15 Municipal Council seats.

Now my question: **What is the formula/method used for divvying up the seats?** Why did the 1st place (with 38.15% of the vote) get 11+2 (municipal/community council) seats, the 2nd-place (also exactly 38.15% of the vote) get 3+1, the 3rd-place (11.98%) got 1+0, and 4th-place (11.70%) got 0+0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll explain the distribution of municipal seats, because the others are fairly straightforward (the two main voted parties get a seat each, the seat left is assigned by seniority).

From the page that you link, in the explanation of [voting in communes with more than 1000 inhabitants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipal_elections_in_France#Communes_With_More_than_1000_inhabitants)<sup>1</sup>, it explains:

> Municipal elections in communes with more than 1000 inhabitants use the rule majority voting with proportional rate:

and it explains it as a "most voted list gets a majority" system:

> the first half (rounded if necessary to the next whole number) are assigned seats to be filled from the list with the most votes; other seats are distributed among all the lists present in the final round that took more than 5% of votes cast (including the majority list) which is called proportional to the strongest average.

So:

- Crouzille won, and his list gets automatically 8 seats (15 / 2, rounded upwards).
- The other 7 seats are divided based in vote proportion, resulting in 3 aditional seats for Crouzille (11 in total), 3 seats for Olivier (same number of votes) and 1 seat for Barradis.

---

<sup>1</sup>[This other page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Front-de-Pradoux) lists Saint Front de Pradoux as having 1.092 inhabitants in 2008, so it should be still in the 1000-1500 range.

Comment: Ah I see. But I still don't understand why for example the 4th-place Crabanac (with 11.70% of the vote) gets 0.

Comment: Because he does not get to. If you put in in terms of votes/seat, you get  92,3 votes/seat for the two most voted lists, and 87 votes/seat for the third. The last one has 85 votes, giving him a seat would mean taking it away from a list with a better proportion of votes.

Answer (score 2):

The key insight is that there are only 7 seats to divide. The first 8 go to the winning list (to ensure it has a majority no matter what) and only the remainder is distributed by proportional representation. With only 7 seats, the threshold to have a guaranteed seat is quite high and there is always quite a bit of distortion: 3 seats is 43% of 7 but 2 is only 29%. Even Barradis is somewhat lucky to have a seat.

Finally, the “*conseil communautaire*” is a part of a separate institution including several municipalities (see [communauté de communes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communaut%C3%A9_de_communes) on Wikipedia). It doesn't really make sense to add those seats as those are in fact the same people getting an additional mandate.